# How to configure m2e eclipse plugin to support parent version ranges?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

Since **Maven 3.2.2** supports defining the pom's [parent version with ranges](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2199), is it possible to configure m2e plugin to resolve the version range? How?

**Edit 1:** *(2014-09-29 @ 09:50 AEST)*

Scenario: Importing a maven project with the following parent definition into eclipse with m2e plugin (the project is not a module of its parent)

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <version>[1.0,1.1)</version>
</parent>
```

M2E plugin fails to resolve the version range, showing this error message in the POM editor:

`Could not transfer artifact groupId:artifactId:pom:[1.0,1.1) from/to nexus-releases (http://nexus.proxy/content/groups/public/): Illegal character in path at index 82: http://nexus.proxy/content/groups/public/groupId/artifactId/[1.0,1.1)/artifactId-[1.0,1.1).pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM`

It works when running with `Run as... > Maven install`, see the log snippet below:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: http://nexus.proxy/content/groups/public/groupId/artifactId/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://nexus.proxy/content/groups/public/groupId/artifactId/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://nexus.proxy/content/groups/public-snapshot/groupId/artifactId/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://nexus.proxy/content/groups/public-snapshot/groupId/artifactId/maven-metadata.xml (488 B at 0.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://nexus.proxy/content/groups/public/groupId/artifactId/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 2.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://nexus.proxy/content/groups/public/groupId/artifactId/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 2.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://nexus.proxy/content/groups/public/groupId/artifactId/[1.0,1.1)/artifactId-[1.0,1.1).pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://nexus.proxy/content/groups/public/groupId/artifactId/[1.0,1.1)/artifactId-[1.0,1.1).pom
```

---

*PS.: The question is not whether or not this is a good practice, please refer to [Benjamin's comment](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2199?focusedCommentId=324686&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-324686) for some background.*

*Related to [How to configure maven or eclipse in order to use the RELEASE constant within versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371231/how-to-configure-maven-or-eclipse-in-order-to-use-the-release-constant-within-ve)*

Comment: Can you please make your question more clear? You have given lots of links, be more specific so that everyone can post good answer.

Comment: There you go @SanjayaPandey :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fixed on m2e v1.6.x

Bugzilla for M2E [#445883](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445833) (duplicated of [#438441](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438441))

As a workaround, using LATEST or RELEASE as parent pom's version should work.